# Extending SUDO timestamp in a BASH script

Tags: macos, bash, timestamp, sudo

There's a BASH script that might need more than 5 minutes to run a list of commands (majority are sudo)...What's the alternative?

Some say...

Use `sudo -v`

seems like a good option, although, after reading Apple's [sudo(8) Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html), it was said...

> If given the -v (validate) option, sudo will update the user's time stamp, prompting for
>                      the user's password if necessary.  This extends the sudo timeout for another 5 minutes
>                      (or whatever the timeout is set to in sudoers) but does not run a command.

I'm concerned with *prompting for the user's password if necessary*. What do they mean "if necessary"?

If I have sudo -v in a bash script that, let's say, executes roughly 4 minutes since the last time sudo was used (1 minute left on timestamp). Thus, giving us another 5 minutes to the timestamp - Right?

As for the other option, someone mentioned to use a loop command for updating a timestamp.

```
while true; do sudo -n true; sleep 60; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &
```

Can the above code work?

Comment: Well, you already quoted the alternative: "or whatever the timeout is set to in sudoers"... Why can't you read what you quoted yourself?

Comment: Why don't you run the first script with `sudo` and then there's no need to do it again inside the script?

Comment: @dtmilano Sometimes it's not an option. You don't want to have UID 0 for everything, or you can easily mess us permissions and stuff (e.g., creating files with root:wheel). The general advice is only sudo when necessary.

Comment: @dtmilano I'm using osascript to call a .sh file using administrative privileges, thus allowing me to execute a list of sudo commands, but there might be a time when a script is called longer than 5 minutes (default timestamp).

Comment: @4ae1e1 I rather not edit the sudoers. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: @JamesDean Sometimes there's no easy option. It's okay to refresh over and over again if all your individual commands are fast, but sometimes a single command can run for hours. It might be possible to have a parallel process that does nothing but refreshing `sudo` verification, but (1) I'm not sure if `sudo -v` from another process counts (probably not, if I'm the designer); (2) that would be ugly. I've encountered situations like this before, where I just temporarily append to `/etc/sudoers` (programatically of course) and restore at the end.

Comment: Re "I'm not sure" from my comment above: I tried and it actually works.

Comment: As I said, constantly revalidate in a separate process. Anyway, you can try this example script I just whipped up https://gist.github.com/798c9ee18a9f33e83b4e (run with `-h` to see usage info; you may want to save some waiting by setting `timestamp_timeout` to something like 0.1 first with `visudo`).

Comment: You said you don't want to edit sudoers, but editing so that you can run those specific commands with no password at all would be a good alternative.

Comment: Did you read my example script? Running `refresh_sudo_indefinitely` in the background creates a separate process. You can replace everything after `refresh_sudo_indefinitely &` with whatever you need to do. Just remember to `kill $(jobs -p)` at the end, or your script won't return.

Comment: I don't care about a, b, c, osascript or whatever... Again, what I'm saying is in http://git.io/v8btW. It can do anything of this type. I made it pretty readable (hopefully so).

Comment: @4ae1e1 I'm enjoying your explosive attitude however, I took a look at the bash script you created. I would need you to explain what each line of code is doing please; just a little convoluted..till then, there needs to be another alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answering my own question, I did however, found a solution.

replace *userpassword* with **your password**:

```
 echo "userpassword" | sudo -S -v
```

Use **variable**:

```
echo "$var" | sudo -S -v
```

or

If you exceed 5 minutes, use **The while loop**:

```
while true; do sudo -v; sleep 300; kill -0 "$$" || exit; done 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: storing password in plaintext is not a wise thing

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
sudo -nv
```

- -n   non-interactive
- -v   attempt to refresh privileges

This command will output nothing if sudo rights are still available for the current context. If they are not available the command will output:

```
$ sudo -nv
sudo: a password is required
```

This way it will not ask and you can build your script around these output conditions.